# Nothing is shown when running a d3 sample code

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am quite new to d3.js and javascript.
I just want to try out some d3 sample code.

I copied over the d3.js code from [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/sunburst/2?intent=fork).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
  .node circle {
    fill: #999;
  }

  .node text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }

  .node--internal circle {
    fill: #555;
  }

  .node--internal text {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  }

  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: rgb(214, 15, 145);
    stroke-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  form {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  label {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<svg width="928" height="928"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script>

  const data = {
        name: "Name",
        children: [
          {
            name: "A_F",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Alice",
              },
              {
                name: "Bob",
              },
              {
                name: "Charlie",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: "G_P",
            children: [
              {
                name: "Gary",
              },
              {
                name: "Helen",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };

  // Specify the chart’s dimensions.
  const width = 928;
  const height = width;
  const radius = width / 6;

  // Create the color scale.
  const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.quantize(d3.interpolateRainbow, data.children.length + 1));

  // Compute the layout.
  const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data)
      .sum(d => d.value)
      .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
  const root = d3.partition()
      .size([2 * Math.PI, hierarchy.height + 1])
    (hierarchy);
  root.each(d => d.current = d);

  // Create the arc generator.
  const arc = d3.arc()
      .startAngle(d => d.x0)
      .endAngle(d => d.x1)
      .padAngle(d => Math.min((d.x1 - d.x0) / 2, 0.005))
      .padRadius(radius * 1.5)
      .innerRadius(d => d.y0 * radius)
      .outerRadius(d => Math.max(d.y0 * radius, d.y1 * radius - 1))

  // Create the SVG container.
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, width])
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

  // Append the arcs.
  const path = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .join("path")
      .attr("fill", d => { while (d.depth > 1) d = d.parent; return color(d.data.name); })
      .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.current) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
      .attr("pointer-events", d => arcVisible(d.current) ? "auto" : "none")

      .attr("d", d => arc(d.current));

  // Make them clickable if they have children.
  path.filter(d => d.children)
      .style("cursor", "pointer")
      .on("click", clicked);

  const format = d3.format(",d");
  path.append("title")
      .text(d => `${d.ancestors().map(d => d.data.name).reverse().join("/")}\n${format(d.value)}`);

  const label = svg.append("g")
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("user-select", "none")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .join("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.current))
      .attr("transform", d => labelTransform(d.current))
      .text(d => d.data.name);

  const parent = svg.append("circle")
      .datum(root)
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("pointer-events", "all")
      .on("click", clicked);

  // Handle zoom on click.
  function clicked(event, p) {
    parent.datum(p.parent || root);

    root.each(d => d.target = {
      x0: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x0 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
      x1: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x1 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
      y0: Math.max(0, d.y0 - p.depth),
      y1: Math.max(0, d.y1 - p.depth)
    });

    const t = svg.transition().duration(750);

    // Transition the data on all arcs, even the ones that aren’t visible,
    // so that if this transition is interrupted, entering arcs will start
    // the next transition from the desired position.
    path.transition(t)
        .tween("data", d => {
          const i = d3.interpolate(d.current, d.target);
          return t => d.current = i(t);
        })
      .filter(function(d) {
        return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || arcVisible(d.target);
      })
        .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.target) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
        .attr("pointer-events", d => arcVisible(d.target) ? "auto" : "none") 

        .attrTween("d", d => () => arc(d.current));

    label.filter(function(d) {
        return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || labelVisible(d.target);
      }).transition(t)
        .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.target))
        .attrTween("transform", d => () => labelTransform(d.current));
  }
  
  function arcVisible(d) {
    return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && d.x1 > d.x0;
  }

  function labelVisible(d) {
    return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && (d.y1 - d.y0) * (d.x1 - d.x0) > 0.03;
  }

  function labelTransform(d) {
    const x = (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI;
    const y = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2 * radius;
    return `rotate(${x - 90}) translate(${y},0) rotate(${x < 180 ? 0 : 180})`;
  }

  svg.node();
</script>
```

The only thing I edit is to remove the last `return svg.node();` and change it to `svg.node();`

When I spin up a local http server (`py3 -m http.server 8000`), I found that there is nothing shown in the browser and there is no error when I click the `inspect`.

Just want to learn how to triage this issue and trouble shoot. Thank you!

Comment: SVG.node() just returns a node, it doesn't append it to the body, instead of d3.create("svg"), replace with d3.select("body").append("svg").

Comment: Thank you @AndrewReid.

I replaced the `const svg = d3.create("svg")` with `const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")`, and kept the remaining intact. Just tried it again and nothing shown in the browser. Any pointers? Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit annoying that the canonical Observable examples are not as portable as they could be - but usually there are only a few changes required. I'm not positive the body tag is added automagically. On looking again, there is a SVG tag already - I'd use just d3.select("svg") as there is no body tag (d3.create -> d3.select). I may be missing something trivial - but I have to run away from the desk for a few hours.

Comment: Thank you again @AndrewReid.
I just edit the `d3.create` to  `d3.select`. Still no luck... Any suggestions? Really appreciated your help.

Comment: Well, at least you are altering the DOM now. However, your data is not in the same format as the example: the children in the example have value properties, your data does not, so the hierarchy sum function won't work as expected. I get results if I add a value property to each leaf node (each child without children itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, D3 canonical examples are generally found on Observable, which while interactive and useful, doesn't translate to regular 'ol javascript without a change or two.

First, the `return svg.node()` is used by Observable to return a detached DOM element in order to display it. The detached node is created with d3.create(). This won't work in a vanilla javascript environment: normally, you'd append the SVG directly with `d3.select("parentElement").append("svg")` or select it if already exists, as in your code (`d3.select("svg")`).

However, your example has a data format where the leaf nodes (nodes that have no children themselves) have a value property:

```
 "children":[{"name":"AgglomerativeCluster","value":3938},{"name":"CommunityStructure","value":3812}
```

While your data does not:

```
children: [{ name: "Alice", }, { name: "Bob", },
```

This matters as the hierarchy uses a sum function to tabulate the relative sizes of each node:

```
  const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data)
     .sum(d => d.value)
```

So you could add a value property to each leaf node, which will generate a visual. However, if each leaf should have the same weighting, then you can use:

```
   const hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(data)
     .count()
```

Where each parent will be weighted according to the number of leaf nodes in each branch.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew!
Actually, I added the `value` field to each leaf and it worked. Then, I start thinking of setting default value to leaves or giving equal weight to each leaf. Your solution to use `.count()` is awesome. Thanks!